# Why isn't the Code Analysis tab showing on my project properties in Visual Studio 2010 Premium?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

Either I'm going mad or the **Code Analysis** tab in Visual Studio has disappeared (or both).

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium (I know this feature isn't in VS 2010 Professional) with Service Pack 1.

My project has a **Code Contracts** tab, but shouldn't there also be a **Code Analysis** tab? If I select **Analyze | Configure Code Analysis For [this project]** from the menu, the project settings are displayed but just with whatever tab was previously selected.

If I select **Analyze | Configure Code Analysis For Solution** from the menu, I do get a dialog box.

Am I right in thinking there should be a **Code Analysis** tab for the project? Any idea what might make it not show up?

Comment: Do you have everything selected when you go Add/Remove Progams -> Visual Studio 2010 -> Modify Features?

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be selected. I'm on 32-bit Windows 7, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you upgrade from VS Professional?  If so, did you re-apply SP1 after the upgrade?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu Yes, I did upgrade from VS Professional. I don't think I applied SP1 until after the upgrade, though. In any case, I reapplied SP1 yesterday and it didn't make any difference. Note that I *do* get the **Analyze** menu but not the **Code Analysis** tab.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge, did you manage to fix this issue? I have the same issue on VS2010 Ultimate SP1

Comment: @ThomasLevesque No, I haven't found a solution. I guess that reinstalling cleanly would fix it. I've just been using FxCop and StyleCop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Did you try:

### [`devenv /SafeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)

> Starts Visual Studio in safe mode, loading only the default
>   environment and services.

### [`devenv /setup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx)

> Forces Visual Studio to merge the resource metadata that describes
>   menus, toolbars, and command groups, from all available VSPackages.

### [`devenv /ResetSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

> Restores the default settings for Visual Studio and automatically
>   launches its integrated development environment (IDE). Optionally
>   resets the settings to the specified .vssettings file.

### [`devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx)

> Clears all options to skip loading added to VSPackages by users
>   wishing to avoid loading problem VSPackages, then starts Visual
>   Studio.

---

- Did you notice the small "More Settings" arrow?

[image: Code Analysis tab]

---

- Did you apply or re-apply [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209902)?

---

- If all fails, you should probably uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. There's no "More settings" arrow. Running in safe mode shows a blank tab beneath "Signing" with an error message "An error occurred trying to load the page. Unable to create the designer. File is already opened in an incompatible editor", but it's not obvious whether it's having trouble displaying the Code Contracts or the Code Analysis tab.

Comment: `devenv /ResetSettings` hasn't made any difference either.

Comment: In the end I did have to reinstall.